# how can I move a div by 10px with press of arrow keys in angular 12?

Tags: angular, angular12

I just want to control(move one position to another) div by pressing the arrow button. div should move by clicking on button div as well. I am trying to move center div which is surrounded by four other div. when I click on left div, center div should move to left, if I click on right div then center div should move to right and so on. I know how to do in javaScript, new to angular.

```
goLeft(ev:any){

    //what should I write here, on mouse click move the div by 10px?
  }


if(event.key == "ArrowDown"){
      // what shouls I wright here to move div by 10px from keyboard event.
      console.log(event.key);
    }
```

Comment: You can use the same code you using in the JavaScript to do this, it'll work in the angular too.

Comment: Please share the code explaining what you have already tried and how it differs from your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Create yourself a method, like:

```
move(element: HTMLElement, moveBy: number) {
    // move element
    element.style.top = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + moveBy + "px";
    element.style.left = element.getBoundingClientRect().left + moveBy + "px";
}
```

now call this method in your click handler e.g in your template having access to the html elements. Apologize, i'm currently on mobile so there might be mistakes. You will have to add a Listener like:

```
  @HostListener('window:mouseup', ['$event'])
      public mouseup(_: MouseEvent): any {
         // implement your action here
  }
```